# Website warns about unsafe browsing

Tags: macos, browser, ssl

On MacOS High Sierra, a website claims unsafe browsing.

In both Chrome and Safari.

This website has a full valid SSL certificate which works on all browsers across Windows, Linux and Android browsers without any problems.

What can I do on Mac to refresh, or revalidate this connection?

The server itself seems working perfectly, based on all other platforms.

Comment: Update your OS. High Sierra went End of Life two years ago.

Comment: Is the time/timezone correct on your MacOS?

Comment: I wonder if the certificate is properly installed - if its missing a chain/intermediate cert it will work in some browsers but not others depending on what root certs it has.

Comment: Perhaps the Mac has an older certificate in its cache, or maybe it's missing a the root Certificate Authority. Which CA has issued this certificate?

Comment: It is issued by SSL.com "SSL Corporation". If it is missing from the root CA, can I somehow refresh it?